# Simple graph proving cardinality of a set is even

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Let G be a simple graph, and let S be the set of vertices of even degree, and T be the set of vertices of odd degree. Prove that the cardinality (number of things in) T is even.

I am new to graph theory so I think this has something to do with the degree-sum theorem: $$\sum_{v \in V} deg(v)=2e$$, but I don't know exactly how to form a proof.  (e represents edges)

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $S \cup T = V$ (and, I forgot rather crucially, $S \cap T = \emptyset$),

$$\sum_{v\in V} deg(v) = \sum_{s \in S} deg(s) + \sum_{t \in T} deg(t) = 2e.$$

You know that each $deg(s)$ is an even number and each $deg(t)$ is an odd number. What happens if the cardinality of $T$ is odd?

Comment: We're only using cardinality in the sense of "the size of a set". S, T, and V are all sets of vertices.